# Pandas convert int to label class

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I made a Multinomial Bayes classification and it returns the index class. So the result looks like this :

```py
    Kelas
0   1
1   1
2   0
```

I wanted to convert the int to the actual class, let's say

```py
1 = Lion
0 = Elephant
```

I found that I can use pandas.replace(), but I don't know how to changing multiple values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary:

```
df['Kelas'] = df['Kelas'].map({0:'Elephant',1:'Lion'})
```